# How to dynamically multiple binding to an ImageView

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I wanted to do mvvmcross binding the following to an ImageView properties:

1) click 
2) ImageUrl - change the image 
3) enabled

```
in Layout file:

<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/imgTest"

    android:src="@drawable/Img_Test"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:maxHeight="80dp"
    android:maxWidth="80dp"   
    android:layout_margin="20dp"   
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"

    local:MvxBind ="      " /
```

in resources

I have both images in the resources folder

1) ImgTest_Normal.png 
2) ImgTest_Grey.png

```
in ivalue Converter :


public class MyTargetImageValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, string>
{
    protected override string Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value)
        {
            return "res:ImgTest_Normal";
        }
        else
        {
            return "res:ImgTest_Grey";
        }
    }
}
```

in Binding :

local:MvxBind ="Click Commands[DisplayCase]; Enabled AuthCommand('View_user'); ImageUrl MyTargetImage(false)"

Why this not working? any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an `MvxImageView` to be able to bind to `ImageUrl`.

So change your AXML layout to:

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgTest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:maxHeight="80dp"
    android:maxWidth="80dp"   
    android:layout_margin="20dp"   
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    local:MvxBind="Click Commands[DisplayCase]; Enabled AuthCommand('View_user'); ImageUrl MyTargetImage(false)" />
```

I have no idea what you are trying to bind to the `Enabled` property, but it doesn't look right.

Comment: I followed your approach. it did not work. I used this combination for image path : 1) res:ImgTest_Normal / ImgTest_Grey  2) Resoures/drawable/ImgTest_Normal or ImgTest_Grey in the converter. There is no error and it did not work. How to I return DrawableId in the converter ?